# Error al instalar el netbeans 8.2 debian 10 i386, pantalla en blanco

Tags: netbeans-8.2

No comprendo porque no arranca normalmente el instalador
He aquí unos datos que creo relevantes:

```
java -version
      openjdk version "1.8.0_232"
      OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_232-8u232-b09-1~deb9u1-b09)
      OpenJDK Server VM (build 25.232-b09, mixed mode)
```

**Espacio:** `45 GB de Espacio Disponible`

**Error:**`NameResolver - to parse Insufficient disk space for extracting the installation data`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En mi caso trabajo desde la consola zsh, asi que en el archivo de:

`$HOME/.zshrc`

Añadimos:

`export _JAVA_AWT_WM_NONREPARENTING=1`

Para aliviar una incompatibilidad con el reparenting de mi gestor de ventanas  BSPWM. Incompatibilidad que producía una pantalla en blanco.